# Can't create "Single-action control" notification android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

The Android Wear UI patterns show the ability to make this notification on Android Wear, however I am not able to find how this is accomplished. I assumed just having one pending 
intent action.

I.E.: `.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action));`

Would achieve this, however I am not able to get this view. Any one know if there is a special flag I need to set for this? Thanks![image: Single Action]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WearableExtender.setContentAction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.WearableExtender.html#setContentAction%28int%29) states:

> Set an action from this notification's actions to be clickable with the content of this notification. This action will no longer display separately from the notification's content.

Use that alongside [WearableExtender.setContentIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.WearableExtender.html#setContentIcon%28int%29) to add the action directly to the first page of the notification.

Note: you'll still need to add the action as your code stated, then use the index of that action as the input to `setContentAction`

Comment: Now I feel lazy. Thanks for the find!

Comment: For me, I am doing exactly the same thing and the icon I set with setContentIcon is shown on amibent mode but it disappears when I extend the notification.