# Button/Action not appearing on Wear notification

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I'm trying to build an Android application that sends a notification to an Android Wear device.

The notification needs to have a content action set, so that the user can directly activate the action by clicking on the button displayed in the notification.

However, using the below code, the action appears on the next page, just like a regular action, and not on the notification:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();

// Create an intent for the reply action
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());

PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Create the action
NotificationCompat.Action action =
        new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark, "ActionTitle", actionPendingIntent).build();

NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Context Text")
                .addAction(action)
                .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                        .setContentAction(0));

// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

After swiping:

[image]

It is supposed to all be on a single page, with the Action button imbedded into the notification, like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not totally sure (hence comment and not answer), but I believe the action to appear inside the main page should be in the `.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setContentAction( /* HERE */ ));`

Comment: @Budius It isn't like so in the sample project, which works (but is too different to directly copy). I tried it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @jco: which sample project are you referring to? Have you tried the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018086/android-wear-notification-setcontentaction-not-working or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601352/cant-create-single-action-control-notification-android-wear ?

Comment: @WaynePiekarski The ContentAction one that comes with the SDK. Additionally, I am almost certain that the two questions you've linked above solve my question. I'll test it out on Monday, and mark my question as duplicate if they do, or are similar enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the possible solutions here:

- [Android Wear - Notification - setContentAction() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018086/android-wear-notification-setcontentaction-not-working)
- [Can't create "Single-action control" notification android wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601352/cant-create-single-action-control-notification-android-wear)